# jQuery - Find active tab

Tags: jquery

I have a list of tabs:

```
<ul class="tabs">
<li><a data-id="1" href="#">AAA</a></li>
<li><a data-id="2" href="#" class="active">BBB</a></li>
<li><a data-id="3" href="#">CCC</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then I have a button:

```
<div id="button">Click Me</div>
```

How can I, when click on the button, access the element that have the class active? I need to be able to get the data-id from the active item.

So, something like this... (this doesn't work!)

```
$("#button").live("click", function(){

        var ref_this = $("ul.tabs li a").find(".active");
        alert(ref_this.data("id"));

});
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You already selected the `a`, and `find()` searches descendants. Try this instead:

```
var ref_this = $("ul.tabs li a.active");
```

Side note: `live()` is deprecated as of version 1.7. `on()` is the new hotness.

Comment: I don't know how I did not think about this. Really simple! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $("#tabs").on("click", function (e) {
        //debugger
        //var ref_this = $("ul.tabs li a.active");

        var target = $(e.target).attr("data-id");
        if (target != null)
             alert(target);
        else
             alert('There is no active element');

       });
});
```

Here is my TAB list

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="gtu-tab">
        <li class="active"><a data-id="1" href="#Boys" id="boys-tab" data-toggle="tab">Boys</a></li>
       <li><a data-id="2" href="#Girls" id="girls-tab" data-toggle="tab">Girls</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs" class="tab-content">
       <div class="tab-pane active" id="Boys">
             <p>Hey....</p>
             <p>Boys are here</p>
       </div>
       <div class="tab-pane" id="Girls">
             <p>Hey....</p>
             <p>Girls are here</p>
       </div>
</div>
```

and button over here

```
<input id="Div1" type="button" value="Click Me"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try on instead of live:

```
$("#button").on("click", function(){

        var ref_this = $("ul.tabs li a").find(".active");
        alert(ref_this.data("id"));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others have already mentioned: since jQuery v1.7 the live() method is deprecated.

This should work:

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
  var active_button = $('.tabs li a.active');
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, `live()` `jQuery` method is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.7/) since `1.7` version. You should use `on()` `jQuery` method instead ([on() jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/)) and change your `CSS` selector like this :

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
    var ref_this = $('ul.tabs li a.active');
    alert(ref_this.data('id'));
});
```

And if the `active` class is optional (`0` to `1`. Not `n`), you should check if there exists an `active` element for example (just a simple way to do) :

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
    var ref_this = $('ul.tabs li a.active');

    if(ref_this)
        alert(ref_this.data('id'));
    else
        alert('There is no active element');
});
```

Answer (score -3):

```
   var activeTab = "AAA";
    $("li").click(function(){
    activeTab = $(this).text();
    });
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.